# How can I import a directory (with subdirectories) into ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was wondering if there is a better way to import a folder (which has subdirectories) that contains notebook files. Currently I have to create a folder on the notebook dashboard and then import a notebook file and repeat for all other files and folders. There are too many to do this manually. Is there a better way to import an entire folder in a couple of command lines or via GUI?
Version of ipython notebook 3.0.0 on python 2.7

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you want to achieve? How are the subdirectories organized. If you go to your directory via the cmd line, you can open ipython notebook in that directory and you will be able to see the files. Otherwise you can browse to the directory from the notebook dashboard.

Comment: Good point. Navigating via command line works well. Thank you. Alternately if I open ipython from a default directory I am not able to locate the folder of interest. Do I have change some setting in the ipython to 'always' load certain paths?